# output json array in php

Tags: php, json

I have this json currently :

```
{"quest_id":"1","quest_title":"Buy 3 pints of draft and a large pizza and then get desert","quest_price":"15","quest_points":"100"}{"quest_id":"2","quest_title":"Hello WOrld","quest_price":"50","quest_points":"10"}
```

I was wondering how I could output this :

```
{"quests":  {"quest_id":"1","quest_title":"Buy 3 pints of draft and a large pizza and then get desert","quest_price":"15","quest_points":"100"}{"quest_id":"2","quest_title":"Hello WOrld","quest_price":"50","quest_points":"10"}
}
```

Here is the code in php:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($number, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        print(json_encode($result));

    }
```

Comment: Did you try something ? It sounds pretty easy to do...

Comment: Spend some time here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: your 2nd bit of JSON is not actually valid. You need to have the 2 quests in a list or something like that.

Comment: You want a done job? I think the best option to learn are the PHP manual, as @TheNail have writed above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array('quests' => array());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($number, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $result['quests'][] = $row
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, get a JSON packet with all the rows, then loop over them to put them in an array, then encode the whole array:

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $out = array('quests' => array());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $out['quests'][] = $row;
  }
  print json_encode($out);
?>
```

Comment: Change `$out[] = $row` to `$out['quests'][] = $row`

Comment: Wrong again. need to be exactly: `$out['quests'][] = $row;`. If are only `$out['quests'] = $row;`, every time you array will be ovewrited.

Comment: I'm sure there's an expression for the experience of having such an obvious mistake caught, twice, but I can't place it.