# Not getting the output

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the data from the database for which I created a php file. It returns the name as the reply to the call. the website it [Ensignweb](http://www.http://ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php)

the program code goes like this.

The php file is like this

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","databasename","password");

mysql_select_db("ews_app");

$query = mysql_query("select name from comment");
if(!empty($query)){
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){

WHILE($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)):

$comment = array();
$comment["name"] = $row['name'];
echo "$comment<br>";
echo json_encode($comment);
echo "<br>";
endwhile;
    }
}
?>
```

The java code goes like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView httpStuff;
    HttpClient client;
    JSONObject json;
    final static String URL = "http://www.ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        new Read().execute("name");
    }

    public JSONObject lastTweet() throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException{
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL); 

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();//return 200 if execution is success
        if(status==200){
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
            return last;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                json = lastTweet();
                return json.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            httpStuff.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

But It is not displaying the json reply. I'm stucked in it from past few days.
Please help me out of it. I really need it.

Comment: What response are you getting? (raw data)

Comment: the website http://www.ensignweb.com/sandbox/app/comment11.php response is not valid json string.

Comment: Because your webservice isn't returning response in valid json format.. the return string should be something like this {
"key": [
{"name":"bernard"},
{"name":"second"}]
}

Comment: The return format is Array
{"name":"bernard"}
Array
{"name":"Vijay"}
Array
{"name":"vikas_admin"}
Array
{"name":"vikas_admin"}. How to make it. Please help

Comment: How to get a valid json string return

Comment: I have attached the php code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Look at the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706008/output-json-array-in-php